# WorkbenchJ - Error: aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I found a few other threads with this error message on the site but the solutions there did not seem to work for me.

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT 
    o.name as Name, 
    o.vrank_tav__c as Vrank,
    COUNT(c.enterprise_id) AS #_users_enterprise
FROM 
    (community_csv_james c JOIN 
    salesforce_data_opportunity o ON
c.enterprise_id = o.enterprise_id__c)
GROUP BY #_users_enterprise, Name, Vrank
ORDER BY #_users_enterprise DESC;
```

When I run it on SQL Workbench J, I get the following error:

```
SELECT 
    o.name as Name, 
    o.vrank_tav__c as Vrank,
    COUNT(c.enterprise_id) AS #_users_enterprise
FROM 
    (community_csv_james c JOIN 
    salesforce_data...

ERROR: aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause
```

I've tried a few variations of this but I that promoted different error messages. How should I write this query?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter which client you run the SQL statement from, MySQL is going to return an error. The statement doesn't make sense. It's not at all clear what result you expect to return. Without example data and sample output, or some kind of specification other than a malformed SQL statement, we're only guessing. As currently presented, there isn't any answer to the question... only guesses.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to include the results from your aggregate function (your Count()) in your group by.  The count is going to be associated with a distinct name/Vrank so you would only need to group on those.  That's why it's giving you that specific error.

```
GROUP BY Name, Vrank
```

[MySQL documentation for GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)